# Angular exception: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing VIES

Tags: angular, typescript, soap, request, access-control

I have been searching in a way to implement a VAT validation for European Tax Numbers, however I'm having an issue with it.

To make the request I'm using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-vat

With this I could simple do:

```
validade(country.TPA_CODI, this.form.get('CLI_NCON').value, function(err: any, validationInfo: any) {
  if (validationInfo.valid) {
    (...)
  } 
});
```

Then I start getting the error:

[image]

Searching in how to solve the issue I got into this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773426/2486919

Ok, from here I could add an extension to chrome and test if it's doing something and yes, it's working. The issue is that this extension add the allow origin headers to the server response and thats how I'm getting the response in my Angular page.

I have done a bit more research and most of the answers are the same,

> add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *; to your server / webconfig

Ok, for most of the cases it might work, but I'm invoking a webservice that I doesn't have control of, so what can I do here?

The webservice is this one: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

For what I have seen, I think it only accepts SOAP requests.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @djain4 I have done a deploy to a lab environment to test it and it gives the same error, but instead of localhost, the url that I'm accessing.

Answer (score 0):

you have  to call webservice using another technology as a back-end like nodeJs.And then call this data into angular.